# What unit is the Marketing Cloud access_token expires_in value using?

Tags: marketing-cloud, accesstoken

When I send a request to this endpoint, https://my-subdomain-info.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token,

This information comes back:

```
"access_token": (I removed the token from this post.) 
"token_type": "Bearer", 
"expires_in": 1079
```

**What does the 1079 refer to?** 1079 what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is seconds. The lifetime of the token is 20 minutes (20*60=1200), as per this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm

Normally I store the expiry timestamp in the system integrating with SFMC, which allows me to generate a new token well before the expiry.

Comment: You were 10 seconds faster than me ^^ I'll delete my answer as it pratically say the same thing..

Comment: I am glad to see I am not the only one to provide the fastest developer support on the planet, @RachidMamai :-)

Comment: I swear y'all have auto responses set up sometimes

Comment: Hi Lukas - Your response answers the question I asked, but doesn't address this part of it: Why is the access token expiring after 5 minutes when the expires_in value is 1079 and should be approximately 20 minutes?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I don't see a relation between your timestamps and the token.

Comment: @GailParsloe - yes, please give more context on the timestamps. It currently is too vague for us to make the connection to the authToken.

Comment: Lukas - Your updated answer (that you don't think the timestamps in my notes above are related) is perfect! Based on that info, I did some more testing and found that you are correct.   I thought a soap response that I was receiving was missing data because the token had expired. The token had not expired (and the soap issue I was having was something else).  I removed that part of my question.